# ¿Calculo Valor Actual o VA en SQL Sever?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos dias necesito calcular el **Valor Actual o VA (en excel) en SQL Server** y no encontre una funcion o una manera de realizar el cualculo para SQL

Comment: Si esta es una pregunta+respuesta, deja solamente la pregunta, detallando el escenario, en la parte inferior coloca la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TasaInteresNormal FLOAT;
DECLARE @Plazo INT;
DECLARE @CuotaMaxima FLOAT;

SET @TasaInteresNormal = 40;
SET @Plazo = 36
SET @CuotaMaxima = 200

SELECT  CalculoLinea = ((POWER(1+((@TasaInteresNormal/12)/100), @Plazo)- 1)*@CuotaMaxima)/(POWER(1+((@TasaInteresNormal/12)/100), @Plazo)*((@TasaInteresNormal/12)/100))
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente qué hace la consulta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento. Por último, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.